# Is it possible to check if string exists in csv file

Tags: javascript

I want to check if string exists in Csv file,

I have a Csv file with Urls, i want to to pass Url to variable and then check if this Url exists in Csv file.

Is it possible to do with JavaScript?
And how it would look like?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Can you please post some example

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you write your question in a way that will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var file = "file:///C:/Users/Viktor/Documents/Google_WebParsing.txt";
var str = "www.google.com";

function readTextFile(file,str)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                //search for text
                if (allText.indexOf(str) > -1)
                   alert(true);
               else
                   alert(false);
                //alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile(file,str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try something like that:

```
function findInFile(file, searchStr)
{
    var oFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oFile.open("GET", file, true);
    oFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(oFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(oFile.status === 200 || oFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = oFile.responseText;
                //search for text here
               if (allText.IndexOf(searchStr) > 0)
                   return true;
               else
                   return false;


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you returning to?

Comment: @ElenaDBA i passed into var file the path to csv file and to searchStr word that it nee to search in file, but it didn't work no errors showing

Comment: @ElenaDBA i uploaded a code i manage to solve but cannot solve, how to check if string is exactly same as in file, lets say if i search for :www"  it returns true, but i need to check for exactly url

Comment: what happens if you pass url as a second parameter?

Comment: @ElenaDBA  can you please edit your answer, so i can check how it will looks like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117743/discussion-between-andrew-and-elenadba).